# Mule multi-transactions and multiple resources configuration

Tags: transactions, mule

I have a requirement to do the following with a batch order:

- Split the order in multiple orders

  2. Perform custom transformations on the orders
  3. Save the batch order payload
  4. Save the individual order details+ 3 other database inserts are done
  5. Perform an Enrichment on each order
  6. Send the individuals orders to a downstream queue for further processing

The fundamental part of the process is that if the 4 database insertions fail, the orders should not be sent to the queue for further processing. It is clear that this is a multi-resource transaction but how can this configuration be done using multi-transaction for the queue as well as database insertions? In trying to create a multi-transaction configuration I discovered that the foreach cannot be used as a child element of the multi-transaction element. I would appreciate any guidance as to how to perform such a configuration

```
  <transformer component.. for splitting orders
  <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each Order"
            rootMessageVariableName="Original">
            <component... for enrichment
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="orders.queue"
                exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-                      ref="amqConnector"
                doc:name="JMS - Send to Order Queue"/>
        </foreach>
                <db:insert config-ref="DBConfig" doc:name="Insert_Order_l">
                   <db:parameterized-query.....
                <db:insert>
                <db:insert config-ref="DBConfig"..
                <db:insert config-ref="DBConfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all DB and JMS endpoints in a **Transactional** scope. Something like this:

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="blah"  doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
<jms:connector name="JMS" validateConnections="true" doc:name="JMS"/>
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="blah" password="blah" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="blahFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File" path="blah"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
            <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query/>
            </db:insert>
            <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query/>
            </db:insert>
            <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query/>
            </db:insert>

            <jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" queue="blah">
                <jms:transaction action="JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE"/>
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        </transactional>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Comment: But these are different transactional resources i.e. database and jms queue. The Mule documentation clearly states the ee:multi-transaction resource demarcation should be used as an alternative to xa transactions.

Comment: This solution using a simple `transactional` scope would result in a *Only a single resource can be bound to this type of transaction* exception.